# Why can't the WP-CLI installer find my php.ini?

Tags: paths, command-line, php.ini, wp-cli

I am trying to install WP-CLI on my Mac using the standard installation command (found here: http://wp-cli.org), yet I am receiving the following error message:

> `#!/usr/bin/env php`
>
> Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
>   Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:
>
> The detect_unicode setting must be disabled.
>   Add the following to the end of your `php.ini`:
>      `detect_unicode = Off`
>
> A `php.ini` file does not exist. You will have to create one.
>   If you can not modify the ini file, you can also run `php -d option=value` to modify ini values on the fly. You can use '-d' multiple times.
>
> ### Installing the main WP-CLI package...
>
> Could not open input file: composer.phar
>
> ### Installing the Boris package...
>
> Could not open input file: composer.phar
>
> WP-CLI files have been succesfully installed.
>
> To test, run:
>
> `/Users/[username]/.composer/bin/wp --info`

When I run the test it reports `no such file or directory`.

I have not installed the bundled PHP that ships with OS X, nor am I using any kind of package. I use MAMP for my local development environment, so my php.ini file is located here:

```
`/Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.4.4/php.ini`
```

Can anyone please advise on the best way to get around this error message? Thanks.

Comment: When do you get this error? Is this after you've run installer.sh? I can't see a matching error message and the installer is aware of MAMP being installed in /Applications https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli.github.com/blob/master/installer.sh#L5-L9

Comment: yes, I get this error after running `curl http://wp-cli.org/installer.sh | bash`. I just updated my original post with the full error message.

Comment: Do any of the [Alternative Install Methods](http://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/wiki/Alternative-Install-Methods) work for you?

Comment: no, neither of the Alternative Install methods work. In both cases I receive the exact same error message.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to be really old. No Composer involved now a days to install wp-cli. Just curl, chmod, and copy the file as indicated in http://wp-cli.org/ (:

Now, if anyone wants to add a specific include_path for wp-cli to be aware of (which is how I found this Q) there's 2 options: set a WP_CLI_PHP environment variable OR set include_path in a local php.ini file and modify the wp script to add the -c option after `/path/to/php`.

Comment: An alias in ~/.bash_profile to the absolute path will work for some stuff after the chmod.